# Naming subblocks from any metablock using one single class?

Tags: java, minecraft-forge

I'm trying to make so that only one class is needed to name the subblocks from any metablock that uses this class registration, i.e., naming them as if they were a parameter value, but without using one.

Although this revolves around an API (Minecraft Forge), I think it's a Java question, so I make here a quick explanation of how what I intend to do works.

A metablock is composed of subblocks, that are variations of the same block (e.g., the same block but only the texture and name changes). Each subblock needs a name to identify it. These names are listed in the class `ExampleItemBlock` in a `String[]`, and then are named in the format `MetablockName.SubBlockName` (e.g.: `ExampleMetablock.blue`, `ExampleMetablock.green`, etc.), using

```
// ExampleItemBlock Class

public static final String[] SUBNAMES = new String[] {"blue", "green", "yellow"};

@Override
public String getUnlocalizedName(ItemStack itemStack) 
{
    int i = itemStack.getItemDamage();
    return getUnlocalizedName() + "." + SUBNAMES[i];
}
```

Then, the metablock `ExampleMetablock` is instantiated and registered using

```
// Class where the registrations are made  

public static Block ExampleMetablock = new ExampleMetablock(); 

GameRegistry.registerBlock(ExampleMetablock, ExampleItemBlock.class, "ExampleMetablock");
```

After this, everything works with no problem, however I have to create a new *ItemBlock class for each new metablock I make, and I don't think this is a good or appropriate thing to do, and I think it's better to create one single class that will be used by any future metablock.

As it's noticeable, the second parameter of `GameRegistry.registerBlock()` method (that is a method from the API) requires a value of type `Class`. And that's the problem: how would I turn the `ExampleItemBlock` class dynamic without using instances?

I even tried to add a String[] parameter in `ExampleItemBlock` constructor and then use an instance with the names in place of the class, but just as expected it stated type mismatch.

I searched everywhere for someway to achieve that, but I only found two ways:

**1.** create an ItemBlock class for each new metablock;
**2.** change `SUBNAMES[i]` in `getUnlocalizedName()` to `i` or `itemStack.getItemDamage()`, that will cause the subblocks to be named as numbers instead of names (e.g.: `ExampleMetablock.0`, `ExampleMetablock.1`, etc.), not needing to use String[] or anything, and making it an universal class. However, this way is also very impractical, because this complicates a lot when identifying which subblock is which.

I also searched through some mods on GitHub, but didn't found anything related to this in the code (that I know of).

So my question is: is there someway to make an universal *ItemBlock class, but still naming subblocks with names (words)?

Classes content: [ExampleMetablock](http://pastebin.com/K2GSFH1Q), [ExampleItemBlock](http://pastebin.com/4jREDvTw).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding out that the solution is in Forge itself, as can be seen [here](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-mods/modification-development/2608361-naming-subblocks-from-any-metablock-using-one).

But for information's sake, I'll explain the solution.

---

I didn't know it, but the method `GameRegistry.registerBlock()` also accepts a fourth parameter, of type `Object[]`. So just need to put the list of names inside `Object[]`, only create the `String[]` field from `ExampleMetablock`, and pass the defined `Object[]` parameter's values to the `String[]` field. Like so:

```
public static String[] SUBNAMES;
private IIcon[] icon;

public ExampleMetaBlock(Material material, String name, CreativeTabs tab, String[] subnames)
{
    super(material, name, tab);
    SUBNAMES = subnames;
}
```

Instead of using the class `ExampleItemBlock`, a separately created class, in the `Class` parameter, I recommend that you use instead an already existing class in Minecraft code that does practically the same thing as `ExampleItemBlock`, which is the `ItemMultiTexture` class (this in case there's nothing additional that aren't in `ItemMultiTexture` class). Looking the registration like this:

```
public static final String[] SubNames = new String[] {"blue", "green", "yellow", "red"}; 
public static Block ExampleMetablock = new ExampleMetablock(Material.rock, "ExampleMetablock", Tabs.ExampleModTab, SubNames); 

GameRegistry.registerBlock(ExampleMetablock, ItemMultiTexture.class, "ExampleMetablock", new Object[]{SubNames});
```

However, this won't compile. The error `NoSuchMethodException` will occur in the registration line (`GameRegistry.registerBlock` ....).

The `ItemMultiTexture` class constructor takes the set values in `registerBlock()` method parameters that matches its constructor parameters types, that are `Block, Block, String[]`.

Was provided a `String[]`? Yes. Was provided a `Block`? Yes. Was provided a second `Block`? No. "There is no such method", there is no constructor from `ItemMultiTexture` with parameters `Block, String[]`.

This happens because, as said, the constructor from `ItemMultiTexture` requires two `Block` values.

To solve that, simply create a new class (or edit `ExemploItemBlock`) extending `ItemMultiTexture` which `super`s the two `Block` parameters. Like so:

```
public class ItemMultiTextureHelper extends ItemMultiTexture
{
    public ItemMultiTextureHelper(Block block, String[] names)
    {
        super(block, block, names);
    }
}
```

And `registerBlock()` like this:

```
GameRegistry.registerBlock(ExampleMetablock, ItemMultiTextureHelper.class, "ExampleMetablock", new Object[]{SubNames});
```

And one last thing, but not less important: **remove** the `static` modifier from `SUBNAMES`, otherwise this will cause a total mess on your new metablocks, like all metablocks's sub-blocks being named with the same name as the ones from the first metablock created, repeated sub-blocks, etc.
(I experienced these issues just now, and fixed removing `static`.) So the correct is actually this:

```
public String[] SUBNAMES;
```

Answer (score 0):

What i'd suggest is making one base class that does all your functionality.

```
public class BaseItemMetaBlock {
    .....
}
```

This one has all your functionality for your meta block rendering stuff, but does not get assigned to any block.

Then, have a block

```
public class MySuperAwesomeBlockItem extends BaseItemMetaBlock {
    public MySuperAwesomeBlockItem(Block block) {
       super(block);
    }
}
```

Because the ItemBlock gets associated with the block itself, you could do some programming magic fetch the enum(s) that define the blockstates to return the name you want.

What I did was give my blocks a special interface so I could invoke my own methods after casting them to a general purpose intface

```
 @Override
 public String getUnlocalizedName(ItemStack stack) {
    return super.getUnlocalizedName(stack) + "." + ((IMetaBlockName)this.block).getSpecialName(stack);
  }
```

something like that anyways.

Comment: Thanks, I already found a solution in Forge itself. I'll post an answer in a moment with the solution.